# Operator norm of a Hilbert-Schmidt Kernel

Tags: operator-theory, normed-spaces

In the book Sadri Hassani, the author is trying to solve Fredholm Integral equation using Liouville–Neumann series. Here, they find the norm of an example operator in the following way:-

[image: Doubt]

I don't understand how the author calculated the operator norm using this formula. The definition of operator norm is given by:-

$\lVert A\rVert_{\mathrm{op}} = \left\{ \sup \frac{\lVert Av \rVert}{\lVert v \rVert }\; \colon\;v\in V\text{ with } v \neq 0 \right\}$

In a finite dimensional case, the norm is found as the square root of the largest eigenvalue of the matrix $A^TA$. How are the norms computed in an infinite dimensional case?

Comment: They are calculating the $L^2$ norm

Comment: @epiliam Yes, the norm is $L^2$ but my question is that the operator norm is defined with respect to the vector space as mentioned. You should find out the maximum value of the quantity given with respect to all the vectors(in this case functions) $v$ in the vector space.

Comment: I don't think I follow your point. They have calculated the $L^2$ norm of the kernel, not the operator norm. Have they previously specified what $\|\cdot\|$ means? Otherwise, I don't really see where the operator norm comes into this.

Comment: @epiliam Yes, they have used the notation $|| K ||$ for the operator norm.

Comment: @epiliam The author is solving an example of Fredholm Integral equation

Comment: The author appears to be computing the Hilbert-Schmidt norm which is an upper bound for the operator norm: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_operator and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator .

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Your observation seems to be correct. They probably should have mentioned this point explicitly.